# chown username:username .Xauthority

Tags: login, chown

I'm stuck in a login loop Ubuntu 17.04.
When I go to tty1 and type `chown username:roey .Xauthority` taken from [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

It says that my user doesn't exist.

What is the problem?
How can I log back in to Ubuntu-Gnome?

Comment: rm .Xauthority and allow it to get recreated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The  command is

```
sudo chown roey:roey .Xauthority
```

1st `roey` is the user, 2nd is the group `roey`

Comment: +1, but you will need `sudo` if it's not yours already and btw the second `roey` is superfluous as just adding the colon after the first one changes the group as well

Comment: to finish this press ALT+-> several times (in my case it's 6 tty's so 6 times) until you get into the Ubuntu-Gnome login screen and login.

Comment: @Roey Also CTRL+ALT+F7

Comment: That didn't fix my problem, sadly.

Comment: @rafael but did you also get the same error notice? Have a look at the  .xsessions_errors file in your home

Answer (score 9):

If you don't know what username/group you shoud use, I suggest using something like this:

```
sudo chown $USER:`id -gn` .Xauthority
```

- `$USER` will be expanded into your current username.
- `id -gn` will returns the main group of your current user.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `$USER:\`id -gn\`` (note the colon character in the middle)? Also, that would be equivalent to just `$USER:` since `chown` uses the primary group of the specified user if you omit the group name.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Both `:` and `.` will work fine,  didn't know about omitting group like `$USER:`, good point +1 :-)

Comment: check `info coreutils` and the section which is about `chown`. I'll change it to `:` in case of username contains dot.

Comment: Indeed: “New scripts should avoid the use of \`.' because it is not portable […].” Looks like we both learned something today. :-]

Comment: Yeah, I just used it to show an alternative approach and it caused us to learn something new :)